# How to plot a dataframe using date as the x axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a simple dataframe with two columns, 'date' and 'amount'. I want to plot the amount using date as the x-axis.  The first lines of the data are:

```
22/05/2018,52068.67
21/05/2018,52159.19
15/05/2018,52744.03
08/05/2018,54666.21
08/05/2018,54677.51
01/05/2018,53890.59
30/04/2018,54812.25
27/04/2018,52258.23
26/04/2018,52351.47
23/04/2018,49777.04
23/04/2018,49952.44
23/04/2018,49992.44
05/04/2018,53238.59
03/04/2018,53631.09
03/04/2018,53839.64
28/03/2018,50836.78
26/03/2018,51206.67
26/03/2018,51372.02
14/03/2018,51110.17
12/03/2018,51411.31
06/03/2018,51169.91
05/03/2018,51374.57
27/02/2018,48728.85
27/02/2018,48730.5
16/02/2018,44988.25
14/02/2018,41948.03
12/02/2018,43776.31
12/02/2018,43800.31
12/02/2018,43840.11
05/02/2018,29358.96
26/01/2018,39491.0
24/01/2018,36470.03
23/01/2018,36562.76
23/01/2018,36616.61
22/01/2018,36582.46
22/01/2018,36665.71
22/01/2018,36743.31
17/01/2018,36965.3
16/01/2018,37044.6
09/01/2018,42083.65
08/01/2018,42183.39
05/01/2018,42285.41
03/01/2018,41537.51
03/01/2018,41579.51
02/01/2018,41945.32
27/12/2017,43003.33
27/12/2017,43217.29
18/12/2017,38208.63
15/12/2017,38315.53
```

However, the plot gives me points that don't appear in the data.  For example, in May 2018 there is no value near 30000.

[image]

My code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", header=None, names =['date', 'amount'])
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.set_index(['time'],inplace=True)
df['amount'].plot()
plt.show()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to sort your data by date.

Comment: @A.Kot The x-axis in the plot is sorted by date (see the figure in the question) so hasn't that already been done by pandas?

Comment: @A.Kot How can I sort by date?

Comment: As far as I can tell, matplotlib is faithfully plotting your data.  What makes you think there is something wrong?  (when I tried `df['amount'].min()` I get `29358.96` and `df['amount'].idxmin()` returns `'2018-05-02 00:00:00'`

Comment: There is a a amount of 293585.96 at `05/02/2018,29358.96`

Comment: @Chris Right but that is supposed to be May 2018. The problem was the month/day ordering it seems.

Comment: @Bill `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format = '%d/%m/%Y')` fixed it.

Comment: Shame that `pd.to_datetime("05/02/2018")` returns `Timestamp('2018-05-02 00:00:00')`.

Comment: You can also use the "dayfirst" option: `df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=True)`

Comment: @screenpaver Nice! I had never heard of that.

Comment: @screenpaver Nice, yes.  But what I object to is that this is not the default when only the US uses this non-standard convention.  The option should be `monthfirst=True`!

Comment: Just for fun: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to covert the dates to date time using correct format and use pandas plot

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format = '%d/%m/%Y')
df.plot('date', 'amount')
```

[image]

Comment: Nice work.  That explains it.  `29  05/02/2018  29358.96`  never understood why the US decided to reverse day/month in dates when all other countries use dd/mm/yyyy....

Comment: @Bill, yeah the date format does throw you off in the beginning but as is with any topic in programming, your mind gets trained to look for those problem areas

Comment: @Parfait You don't even speak English!  (colour, behaviour, programme, ...).  But we're getting off topic.